# PHP REGEX: Problem with Smiley `:)` and `:))`

Tags: php, regex

**What I want**

---

Hi! I want to replace `:)` to `smile.png` and `:))` to `laugh.png`.

**The problem**

---

The script finds `:)` inside `:))` so `laugh.png` is not shown, only `smile.png`+)

**This is what I have tried so far for `:))`:**

---

`preg_replace("/:)+(?!))/i",$image, $string))`

Some other regexes what I tried:

`"/\:\)+(?=\))/i"`

`"/\:+(?=\)\))/i"`

But nothing want's to work what I tried yet.

Comment: with whatever emoticon thing your doing promise me that I won't be able to type My::Program and get a My:(tongue smiley)rogram. make sure you match spaces or something.

Comment: I'm not going to answer this question because of the unhelpful downvoting of all answers with no comments as to why. Good luck getting an answer.

Comment: +1 for saying what you have and asking what you want, and showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For :) – `(:\)(?!\)))`

Then

For :)) – `(:\)\))`

Comment: First answer that actually answered the op. Funny how many people avoid answering when they see regexp's.

Comment: My bad for not wrapping in `/.../`.. But it works. Tested on rubular.com

Comment: Blindy, unless the op stated that he really wanted a regexp solution, shouldn't we help by posting a better solution?

Comment: @Blindly That's because using a regular expression here hinders the readability and is unnecessarily complex (not to mention less efficient).

Comment: Cool thanks for rubular.com I was searching for hours for a service like this, but most of them sucks...

Comment: @Blindy although I see quite a few questions that are asking for regexps and shouldn't be using them. this one seems fine though.

Comment: @Adam, I see a regexp tag and regexp is mentioned in the title. What more do you want?

Comment: By the way the regex is not even correct. The first one will fail if `:)` is the last thing. It should use negative lookahead or `|$`. But you were very quick to upvote it and downvote the correct solutions, even if they're a better solution for this problem.

Comment: @Artefacto true! What's the fix?

Comment: @Adam I'm more just curious how to make the regex work. I'd use his or Rick's if it were my code.

Comment: @hookedonwinter Sorry, I mistook you for the op.

Comment: I fixed it and also removed the unnecessary escaping of `:`.

Comment: Why are these expressions wrapped in parentheses? It is entirely unnecessary (and less readable here!) to use capture groups for a whole expression, since PHP regex functions already provide `$0` instead.

Comment: What do you mean @Peter Boughton? sry I'm new with regex :S

Comment: @Peter Good question. No real reason.

Answer (score 3):

```
str_replace(array(":))", ":)"), array("laugh.png", "smile.png"), $string);
```

The order is important.

Comment: +1 What's with the downvotes? It's a perfectly valid solution, and it's better than using regex. You don't need regex for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = str_replace(':))', 'laugh.png', $string);
$string = str_replace(':)', 'smile.png', $string);
```

php.net on str_replace:  "If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of ereg_replace()  or preg_replace()."

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do a simple text replace?

First `:))` to `laungh.png`, then `:)` to `smile.png`

Comment: I tried, but I don't know why doesn't works, maybe I could try on a new and clean page :)