# PHP Text to graphical smiley

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP REGEX: Problem with Smiley `:)` and `:))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358260/php-regex-problem-with-smiley-and)

When always i have a similly in text format in a php page such as `;) :-| :-(` can i represent it in graphically ? in all occurrences of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build a function that converts your smiley to HTML image. Like:

```
function parseSmiley($text){
    // Smiley to image
    $smileys = array(
        ';)' => 'blink.png',
        ':-|' => 'scare.png',
        ':-(' => 'bad.png'
    );

    // Now you need find and replace
    foreach($smileys as $smiley => $img){
        $text = str_replace(    
            $smiley,
            "<img src='smiley/path/{$img}' />",
            $text
        );
    }

    // Now only return it
    return $text;
}
```

Now run:

```
echo parseSmiley('Hello you ;)');
```

Comment: Hi my problem is text smiley are dynamic so where to call this function ?

Comment: You need get the string that you need to parse. For instance, if is from a form/POST you can do `echo parseSmiley($_POST['comment']);`

Comment: By what do you mean dynamic? When a user types it in a form and you want him to instantly see a smiley? Then you must use javascript to script the client side.

Comment: You should definitely not apply the function to the $_POST, it's better to apply it when you're rendering the comment.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work:

```
$smileys = array(
    ':)' => 'smile.gif',
    ':(' => 'sad.gif',
    ':D' => 'happy.gif'
);

$ks = array();
$vs = array();

foreach($smileys as $k => $v){
    $ks[] = $k;
    $vs[] = '<img src="' . $v . '" alt="' . $k . '" />';
}

str_replace($ks, $vs, $output); // presuming that you have the whole page output in $output
```

Answer (score 1):

a really easy way to do that, is to replace smiley by a `<img>` tag

```
function smileyText($content) {
    $smiley = array(':)', ':(' ...);
    $graph = array('<img src="..."/>', '<img src="..."/>', ...);

    return str_replace($smiley, $graph, $content);
}
```