# Converting text to smiley if multiple smileys are combined together not working

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to convert text ($icon) to smiley image ($image). I used to do it with str_replace(), but that seems to perform the replace sequentially and as such it also replaces items in previously converted results (for example in the  tag).

I am now using the following code:

```
    foreach($smiliearray as $image => $icon){

        $pattern[]="/(?<!\S)" . preg_quote($icon, '/') . "(?!\S)/u";
        $replacement[]=" <img src='$image' border='0' alt=''> ";

    }
    $text = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$text);
```

This code works, but only if the smiley code is surrounded by whitespace. So basically if someone types ":);)", it won't catch it as two separate smilieys, but ":) ;)" does.

How can I fix it so that also a string of smileys (not separated by space) are converted?

Note that there can be unlimited kinds of smiley codes and smiley images. I do not know beforehand which ones, because other people can submit codes and smileys, so it is not just ":)" and ";)", but can also be "rofl", ":eh", ":-{", etc.

I can partially fix it by adding a \W non-word to the end of the 2nd capturegroup: (?!\S\W), and further by adding a 2nd $pattern and $replacement with a \W to the first capturegroup. But I don't think that is the way it should be done, and it only partially solves it.

Comment: "I do not know beforehand which ones".  Then you're out of luck.  If you don't have a pre-defined list, how are you supposed to know what is something that gets replaced and what isn't?

Comment: I do not see how this can work without a specific ruleset in place. For example, common terms such as `rofl`, `lmao` can be directly replaced. However, when dealing with the custom codes, I would recommend something like - must start with `:` or any other specific character. Then, you will be able to use that starting special character as a delimiter.

Comment: Since there is no reliable separator and you said "_unlimited kinds of smiley codes and smiley images_" i am doubtful of any catchall solution

Comment: Because it works with str_replace, which can search and replace multiple items inside one "word", so it could replace ";):)" with 2 separate smileys. The only problem there is that it is sequential, and thus also replaces items in the <img tag if someone creates a src= code for example. That's why I was looking at preg_replace().

Comment: *I used to do it with str_replace(), but that seems to perform the replace sequentially ...* a true reason to use `strtr()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Text to graphical smiley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106320/php-text-to-graphical-smiley)

Comment: Are you in need of RegEx? Did you find the answer helpful?

Comment: Please improve your question by offering a few different sample inputs that cause trouble and post your desired output for each.  We need to see some realistic data to offer the best possible solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

> I used to do it with `str_replace()`, but that seems to perform the
>   replace sequentially and as such it also replaces items in previously
>   converted results...

A good and true reason to use `strtr()`. You don't even need Regular Expressions:

```
<?php 

// I assume your original array looks like this
$origSmileys = [
    "/1.png" => ':)',
    "/2.png" => ':(',
    "/3.png" => ':P',
    "/4.png" => '>:('
];

// sample input string
$str = " I'm :) but :(>:(:( now :P";

// iterating over smileys to add html tag
$newSmileys = array_map(function($value) {
    return "<img src='$value' border='0' alt=''>";
}, array_flip($origSmileys));

// replace
echo strtr($str, $newSmileys);
```

**[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/QhWrZ)**

Comment: Thanks revo for your suggestion. Before I saw your newest reply, I already experimented a bit with strtr(), and found that later (non smiley) text replacements into html were interfering with it, as in that it sometimes replaces part of the html code. For example if someone makes a smiley with code "class=".

I fixed that by strtr() replace the items into base64_encoded html, encapsulated by a pseudohtml tag. Once everything is executed, I run a preg_replace_callback() to turn it back into html. It is a bit of a workaround, but that seems to work so far.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show this kind of input to provide a more suitable answer.

Comment: No, I mean I checked out strtr(), noticed these problems, and fixed it after your first suggestion of using strtr(), and before I saw your code example.

Comment: So does this specific answer with its approach work in your case? I just want to know If I can improve or add another solution to it.

Comment: It works, and seems to be a more complex way to do it as opposed to how I do it. I currently use the code I initially posted, but changed "$replacement[]" to "$replacement[$icon]" and then do a "strtr($text,$replacement);" instead of the preg_replace ... where $replacement is a base64_encoded string.